# PHP envia email, mas alguns provedores não recebem

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu fiz a função abaixo, que não retorna nenhum erro, porém também não chega em alguns emails de destino *(Yahoo por exemplo)*

```
function enviaEmail($titulo = '', $conteudo = '', $email = '', $nome = '') {
  $to      = $email;
  $subject = $titulo;
  $content = Reconstroi($conteudo, $nome);
  $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
  $headers[] = 'From: meu site@ <contato@meusite.com.br>';

  $status  = wp_mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers);
  if($status==TRUE){return 1;}else{return 0; echo"deu erro no envio do email " 
 .$status;}//return var_dump($status);
}
```

Como fazer o email chegar aos destinos corretos?

Comment: Alguns provedores marcam como spam. Utilize o [`wp_mail` com `SMTP`](https://www.flippercode.com/send-html-emails-using-wp-mail-wordpress/)

Comment: eu estou usando o plugin SMTP Mailer ....mesmo assim, não vai...

Answer (score 0):

Eu tentaria primeiro usar um header mais completo:

```
                    $to="email@destino.com";
                    $subject="Título da Mensagem";
                    $from = 'Email do Sender <noreply@sender.com>';
                    $body='Hi '.$name.', <br/><br>Now You can See Yor main in inbox';
                    $headers = "From: " .($from) . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".($from) . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Return-Path: ".($from) . "\r\n";;
                    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
                    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
                    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";
                    mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

Comment: ainda não foi...